# I accidentally duplicated this window, how do i undo it?

Tags: java, eclipse

I was practicing with Arrays and then I pressed something and the windows duplicated, does someone knows how to fix this?

[image: Duplicated Window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via ***Window > Editor > Toggle Split Editor (Vertical)***